# How to sort an array of objects with with values that contain numbers and string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort by property name in array object.

```js
const arr = [
  {id:1, name: 'A1'},
  {id:2, name: 'A2'},
  {id:3, name: 'A3'},
  {id:4, name: 'B1'},
  {id:5, name: 'B2'},
  {id:6, name: 'A21'},
  {id:7, name: 'A11'},
  {id:8, name: 'A4'},
  {id:9, name: 'A12'},
]

arr.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(
  b.name,
  undefined,
  { numeric: true }
))

console.log(arr)
```

The result I am looking for is 1:A1, 2:A2, 3:A3, 7:A11, 6:A21, 4:B1, 5:B2.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: You'd have to separate the two pieces of data (the letter and the number), parse the numeric string as a number, and sort on the two properties separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localeCompare` with `numeric: true`:

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(
    b.name,
    undefined,
    { numeric: true }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.localeCompare` with [numeric](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#numeric_sorting) option

**DEMO:**

```js
const arr = [{id:1, name: 'A1'},{id:2, name: 'A2'},{id:3, name: 'A3'},{id:4, name: 'B1'},{id:5, name: 'B2'},{id:6, name: 'A21'},{id:7, name: 'A11'}];

const sorted = arr.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => 
    a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
    
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```